# Batching IResourceChangeEvenets for imarker generation using IWorkspaceRunnable in Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, concurrency, eclipse-plugin

As explained in the title, I am trying to create IMarkers using an approach to batch the IResourceChangeEvents. My goal is to create IMarkers in a correct, stable manner. Are there any limitations to using IWorkspaceRunnable (for the purpose of batching the change events), or is it safer to create the IMarkers in the current thread? Are there any foreseeable errors, such as concurrency issues?

This is a bit of an open ended question, but I just want to understand the pros and cons of using IWorkspaceRunnable to create IMarkers. Below are code examples, with and without the batch changes:

```
// Generates marker with the given attributes
public static IMarker generateMarker(final IFile file, final Map<String, Object>     attributes,
                                   final String markerType) throws CoreException, BadLocationException, IOException
{
    if (!attributes.containsKey(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER))
    {
        // Assumes that attributes has a mapping for IMarker.CHAR_START, which is invariant when creating markers in Solstice
        int line = ResourceUtility.convertToDocument(file).getLineOfOffset((int) attributes.get(IMarker.CHAR_START));
        attributes.put(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line + 1); // lines indexed at 1, not 0
    }

    IWorkspaceRunnable r = new IWorkspaceRunnable()
    {
        public void run(@Nullable IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
        {
            IMarker marker = file.createMarker(markerType);
            marker.setAttributes(attributes);

            MarkerField.marker_ = marker; // MarkerField is just an inner class. Functions as a pointer to a pointer.
        }
    };
    file.getWorkspace().run(r, ResourceUtility.getRuleFactory().markerRule(file), 0, null);
    return MarkerField.marker_;
}
```

Alternatively, I can eliminate the batching mechanism, and use the code below:

```
// Generates marker with the given attributes
public static IMarker generateMarker(final IFile file, final Map<String, Object>     attributes,
                                   final String markerType) throws CoreException, BadLocationException, IOException
{
    if (!attributes.containsKey(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER))
    {
        // Assumes that attributes has a mapping for IMarker.CHAR_START, which is invariant when creating markers in Solstice
        int line = ResourceUtility.convertToDocument(file).getLineOfOffset((int) attributes.get(IMarker.CHAR_START));
        attributes.put(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line + 1); // lines indexed at 1, not 0
    }

    IMarker marker = file.createMarker(markerType);
    marker.setAttributes(attributes);

    return marker;
}
```

What are the pros/cons of each method?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, using IWorkspaceRunnable to batch changes is safe. Here are some sources:

An Eclipse Community Forum post that discusses this very issue:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/126939/?srch=batching+resource#msg_126939

The class MarkerUtilities, which uses this same mechanism, almost parallels my code above. An excerpt is below.

My only question now is whether it is safe to access the IMarker that I just created and to return it. I assume this is okay because by the time the IMarker is returned, the IWorkspaceRunnable thread has finished.

```
/**
 * Creates a marker on the given resource with the given type and attributes.
 * <p>
 * This method modifies the workspace (progress is not reported to the user).</p>
 *
 * @param resource the resource
 * @param attributes the attribute map (key type: <code>String</code>,
 *   value type: <code>Object</code>)
 * @param markerType the type of marker
 * @throws CoreException if this method fails
 * @see IResource#createMarker(java.lang.String)
 */
public static void createMarker(final IResource resource, final Map attributes, final String markerType) throws CoreException {

    IWorkspaceRunnable r= new IWorkspaceRunnable() {
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
            IMarker marker= resource.createMarker(markerType);
            marker.setAttributes(attributes);
        }
    };

    resource.getWorkspace().run(r, null,IWorkspace.AVOID_UPDATE, null);
}
```